# Do I need an Apostille for American documents in France?

Tags: france, paperwork, french-citizens, documentation

I am French, born and residing in the United States. I am preparing my request for a certificat de nationalité française (CNF) / Certificate of French Nationality. Does anyone know if I absolutely need to have my documents authenticated by an Apostille?

Comment: Can you tell is what a CNF is?

Comment: For a document like that I would be surprised if they would dispense with the apostille.  The only way you can find out for sure, however, will be to submit the application with those documents not having an apostille and see what happens.

Comment: It depends on exactly what documents.  In general I would say yes, for any documents that would be given an apostille--in particular birth certificate and/or marriage certificate, both of which I've had to get apostilles for.  Basically any vital documents issued by the state.

Comment: To be clear, if they're explicitly asking for an apostille on some document you will definitely need it.

Comment: The CNF is the certificate of french nationality. Since I have an American birth certificate, I need the CNF in order to acquire a passport. The instructions at the service-public do not ask for an Apostile or a French translation. This is why I am not sure about whether or not I will need it. They are expensive, so I would be happy if I could do without it.

Comment: I would be very surprised if the French administration would accept a not-translated, not certified foreign birth certificate as a valid proof. Did your parents declare your birth at the French embassy where you were born ?

Comment: @audionuma, unfortunately, my parents did not declare my birth. Thank you for your advice, I will simply get the documents certified and translated.